# валидация W3Org

Tags: html, css, html-validation

Добрый день 
Есть такой код

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
  <style type="text/css" scoped>

  </style>
</div>

</body>
```

https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

(схема) и ето не проходит валидацию. Пишет

```
Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

И подобная ошибка когда вытягиваю style в скоуп body. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли способ пройти валидацию в такой ситуации?. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, нет. Цитата [отсюда](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-style-element) говорит нам о том, что в HTML 5.2 элемент `<style>` должен быть строго в `<head>`:

> A style element is restricted to appearing in the head of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: `<div style=zzzzz></div>` Кстати, устанавливая стили непосредственно в исходном коде, вы повышаете скорость загрузки страницы, а этот фактор в настоящее время является основным для поискового ранга.